# Using "draggabilly" to create draggable spans

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, draggable

So far on this piece of development I have built this page. As you can hopefully see, it suggests dragging the words on the right sidebar into the slots: http://francesca-designed.me/create-a-status/index.php

The words are pulled from a PHP array, and pressing the button loads some new ones in using AJAX.

I'm trying to implement Dragabilly as it has the functionality and look I want: http://draggabilly.desandro.com/

But I'm running into problems using it. To define which items are draggable, I need to add `class="draggie"` to each of those spans.

Here is the code that creates my spans:

```
<div class="words one">
    <?php foreach (array_rand($poolOne, 4) as $key) {
      echo "<span>".$poolOne[$key]."</span>";
    }?>
</div>
```

So, to make this work I added the "draggie" classname:

```
echo "<span class="draggie">".$poolOne[$key]."</span>";
```

However, I have no idea why, but this breaks the WHOLE page. It seems that it can't call in the AJAX any more. But I am not sure, **why would adding a simple classname to some PHP cause the whole page to break?**

Here is a duplicate of the site code shown in the first link but with the addition of `class="draggie"` - you'll see that the page just shows up blank. Everything is the same apart from the addition of the `draggie` class.

http://francesca-designed.me/create-a-status/index2.php

Comment: Maybe there is an object or a class name with the same name

Comment: Nope, there is nothing else with the name draggie... just the spans.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would kill the entire page, but you're trying to nest double quotes.

`echo "<span class="draggie">".$poolOne[$key]."</span>";`

If there isn't something in PHP-land with the name `draggie`, PHP will throw an error and quit rendering.

I'm guessing that you have errors turned off, too.

You can either replace the double quotes around `draggie` with single quotes (`class='draggie'`), or escape the inner set of double quotes (`class=\"draggie\"`). I'd recommend just switching to single quotes.